# Why is my linear classifier (perceptron) capable of classifying non-linearly separable data?

Tags: java, machine-learning, classification, perceptron

I created a linear classifier for an assignment, but for some reason it's capable of solving the XOR problem; from my understanding, a linear classifier is not supposed to be able to do that. If I input in linearly separable data, it's capable of correctly classifying it; if I input in non-linearly separable data (XOR), it's still capable of correctly classifying it. I'd appreciate any help in understanding why my code is acting that way, and what I should do. This is part of the code that's classifying and causing the problem: *Note: the perceptronActualValueFirstLine is an array that hold the output from the perceptron algorithm (calculation)

```
            //updates the weight for an allowed 100 times    
        while (iterations <= 100 && isLineEqual == false) {
            //loops over the array four times for each instance

                for(int i = 0; i < perceptronActualValueFirstLine.length; i++) {
                    //updates the loop if the desired value does not equal the actual value from the perceptron

                    if(desiredValue[i] != perceptronActualValueFirstLine[i]) { 

    //updates the weight

                        w0 = w0 + (double)(learningRate * (desiredValue[i] - perceptronActualValueFirstLine[i]) * x0[i]);
                        w1 = w1 + (double)(learningRate * (desiredValue[i] - perceptronActualValueFirstLine[i]) * x1[i]);
                        w2 = w2 + (double)(learningRate * (desiredValue[i] - perceptronActualValueFirstLine[i]));


    //updates the actual value

                        perceptronActualValueFirstLine[i] = ((w0 * x0[i]) + (w1 * x1[i]) + (w2) >= 0) ? 1: 0;

                    }
                    //breaks the loop when the actual value equals the desired value

                    if(Arrays.equals(desiredValue,perceptronActualValueFirstLine)) {
                        isLineEqual = true;
                        break; 
                    }        
                }
                iterations++;
            }
        }
```

The output:

```
Desired pairs: 
{0,0} class: 0.0
{0,1} class: 1.0
{1,0} class: 1.0
{1,1} class: 0.0

Linear Classification after training:
{0,0} class: 0.0
{0,1} class: 1.0
{1,0} class: 1.0
{1,1} class: 0.0
```

Comment: How many iterations does training run for? Does the number change on every execution?

Comment: @SusmitAgrawal it changes every time. Here are the numbers after executing it five times: 11, 50, 40, 30, 29

Comment: Can you check if the results repeat for a three input XOR gate?